# What are steps to set up Oracle Java EE 6 SDK in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, installation, java, glassfish

What are steps to set up Oracle Java EE 6 SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before installing make sure that you have Java 6 or newer installed, and accessible.**

Download [Java EE 6 SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-downloads-439814.html) from Oracle.  Make sure to accept the license agreement.  Then, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo -i
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Then execute the script:

```
sh java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix.sh
```

Comment: thank you. but, what are the next steps when the setup dialogs appears?

why do paths export to /etc/bash.bashsrc not to /etc/environment or /etc/profile?

Comment: Once you get the GUI, just follow the instruction in each screen.  As far as the paths, look at [Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)